# Can you initialize an array with an array that may have been autoreleased?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, indexoutofboundsexception

I am trying to figure out an out of bound index issue i am getting in my `newArray` object. I pass in `oldArray` to the method and then use the following:

```
newArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:oldArray];
```

If `oldArray` has been released, would i get an error at this line, or would I get an out of bounds exception when I try to access `newArray`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the above code makes a copy of `oldArray` into `newArray`. Changing `oldArray` in any way (including releasing it) will have no impact on `newArray`, and in any case would certainly not cause a bounds exception.

The most likely cause is that `oldArray` is `nil` at this point, so `newArray` is an empty array when you don't expect it to be. Alternately, `oldArray` may not have as many elements in it as you think it does. Bounds exception means you're reading past the end of the array. It does not have anything to do with memory management.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, i was getting out of bounds at position zero so based on what you are saying oldArray must be empty. Thanks, i will investigate further